# Configure Quartz Scheduler with Oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, datasource, quartz-scheduler, c3p0, oracle-wallet

The application I am supporting uses [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) version 2.3.2 with Oracle database.
User and password credentials are specified in [Quartz configuration datasource section](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigDataSources.html#configure-datasources) of the properties file.
Here is the config properties file which works well:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool,
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5,
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=4,
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=36000000,
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX,
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_,
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO,
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true,
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=1800000,
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate,
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=qzDS,
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver,
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=15000,
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver.oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=15000,
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYQUARTZAPP,

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.user=myquartzapp,
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.password=myquartzapp,

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.maxConnections=10,
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true,
```

I have managed to make Oracle wallet work with a custom database.
This avoids from having plain text password specified in the configuration.
Using a pair of encrypted files, `cwallet.sso` & `ewallet.p12`, [generated with Oracle tool `mkstore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-2419D309-5874-4FDC-ADB7-65D5983B2053).
And specifying its location path in `oracle.net.wallet_location` system (`-D`) or in connection properties.

Unfortunately, I am not able to make it work with Quartz Scheduler.
So when adding wallet files and location and **removing user & password from quartz config**, returns:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Debugging Quartz initialization, it seems that `C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager` gets empty user and password, and is not really using Oracle wallet indications, so it fails to logon. Here the logs and exception thrown:

```
2020-01-19 11:11:18,562 main INFO [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory:1036] instantiate | Using ConnectionProvider class 'org.quartz.utils.C3p0PoolingConnectionProvider' for data source 'qzDS'
2020-01-19 11:11:18,816 MLog-Init-Reporter INFO [c.m.v.l.MLog:212] log | MLog clients using slf4j logging.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,822 MLog-Init-Reporter DEBUG [c.m.v.l.MLog:207] log | Reading VM config for path list /com/mchange/v2/log/default-mchange-log.properties, /mchange-commons.properties, /c3p0.properties, hocon:/reference,/application,/c3p0,/, /mchange-log.properties, /
2020-01-19 11:11:18,822 MLog-Init-Reporter DEBUG [c.m.v.l.MLog:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-commons.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,822 MLog-Init-Reporter DEBUG [c.m.v.l.MLog:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/c3p0.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,822 MLog-Init-Reporter DEBUG [c.m.v.l.MLog:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier 'hocon:/reference,/application,/c3p0,/' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,822 MLog-Init-Reporter DEBUG [c.m.v.l.MLog:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-log.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,915 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-commons.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,916 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-log.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,917 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier 'hocon:/reference,/application,/c3p0,/' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:18,918 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/c3p0.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:11:19,418 main INFO [c.m.v.c.C3P0Registry:212] log | Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.4 [built 23-March-2019 23:00:48 -0700; debug? true; trace: 10]
2020-01-19 11:11:20,089 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.m.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean:204] log | MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0,name=1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0 registered.
2020-01-19 11:11:20,503 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.m.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean:204] log | MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0,name=1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0 unregistered, in order to be reregistered after update.
2020-01-19 11:11:20,504 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.m.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean:204] log | MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0,name=1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0 registered.
2020-01-19 11:11:20,879 main INFO [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory:1220] instantiate | Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2020-01-19 11:11:21,073 main INFO [o.q.c.SchedulerSignalerImpl:61] <init> | Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2020-01-19 11:11:21,075 main INFO [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler:229] <init> | Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2020-01-19 11:11:21,092 main INFO [o.q.i.j.JobStoreTX:672] initialize | Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2020-01-19 11:11:21,130 main INFO [o.q.i.j.JobStoreTX:59] initialize | JobStoreTX initialized.
2020-01-19 11:11:21,139 main INFO [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler:294] initialize | Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'QuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'sm2m-core1579432280918'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

2020-01-19 11:11:21,140 main INFO [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory:1374] instantiate | Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2020-01-19 11:11:21,142 main INFO [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory:1378] instantiate | Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2020-01-19 11:14:47,061 main INFO [c.m.v.c.i.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:212] log | Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYQUARTZAPP, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 120, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2020-01-19 11:14:47,281 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-commons.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:14:47,282 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-log.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:14:47,283 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier '/c3p0.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:14:47,284 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.MConfig:207] log | The configuration file for resource identifier 'hocon:/reference,/application,/c3p0,/' could not be found. Skipping.
2020-01-19 11:14:47,294 main DEBUG [c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool:204] log | com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@747f6c5a config: [start -> 3; min -> 1; max -> 10; inc -> 3; num_acq_attempts -> 30; acq_attempt_delay -> 1000; check_idle_resources_delay -> 0; max_resource_age -> 0; max_idle_time -> 0; excess_max_idle_time -> 0; destroy_unreturned_resc_time -> 0; expiration_enforcement_delay -> 0; break_on_acquisition_failure -> false; debug_store_checkout_exceptions -> false; force_synchronous_checkins -> false]
2020-01-19 11:14:47,295 main DEBUG [c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager:204] log | Created new pool for auth, username (masked): ''.
2020-01-19 11:14:47,296 main DEBUG [c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool:204] log | acquire test -- pool size: 0; target_pool_size: 3; desired target? 1
2020-01-19 11:14:47,297 main DEBUG [c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool:204] log | awaitAvailable(): [unknown]
2020-01-19 11:14:48,690 C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgec1aa71gkv1fm1n5rn52|58feb6b0]-HelperThread-#0 DEBUG [c.m.v.r.BasicResourcePool:207] log | An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1061)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:499)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:663)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1176)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1163)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1908)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

The wallet files are correctly generated since I have tested with a simple application.
Does anybody knows how to configure Quartz to be able to use Oracle wallet?